# How to access the following link element using Watir

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

For instance, if the link contains an `<image>` element as the text, then how do we access it using the watir:

For example:

```
<a><img src="" alt=""\></a>
```

So now I want to access the link using ("text-attribute") then how do we do these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could locate the image and then get the parent element:

```
browser.image(:alt => "").parent.click
```

Or you could find a link that contains the image:

```
browser.links.find{ |a| a.image(:alt => "").exists? }.click
```

If you really want to use the text, then you can use a `:text => ''`. The text locator only checks the visible text of the link - ie it ignores the image.

```
browser.link(:text => '').click
```

Comment: <a href="/buy/shopping_bag.do"><img src="/assets/common/clear.gif" alt="checkout" id="inlineBag" class="universalButtonSprite universalButtonSpriteCheckoutOn"></a> these is how the HTML code is now i want to access these link using text attribute for example e.link(:text,'').click so what i need is what should be the value of text attribute.

Comment: So you want to find a link without text? That does not sound very robust. Why do you not want to use other attributes?

Comment: I know how  to access that with other attributes if in case if i want to access that with text attribute then how do we do that is what i want to know ,because most of the times text attribute takes simple text here it is different that is it has img tag so i want to know how do we access it

Comment: Answer updated. :text only considers the visible text in the link. The image does not contribute any text.

Comment: k so we can't access that using the text attribute

Comment: As shown in the update, you can use the text attribute to find the link. The link has no text, so you are use the locator to find a link with no text.

Comment: <div class="abc" style="width:350px;height:200px;">
<div id="delete5Content" class="abc" style="width:350px;height:200px;">
<div class="deleteConfirm">
<p> My Html code is in these way now I want to access the image in chrome can you plesae let me know how to do @Justin Ko
<p class="text">
<a onclick="return layered();" href="#">
<a onclick="return address.delete('5');" href="#">
<img id="delete5" class="cancelButton" alt="Delete" src="/abc/zyx/clear.gif">
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: @khan, it really depends on what is unique about the image. Finding it is the same as any other element - eg `browser.image(id: 'delete5').click`.

Comment: so here the value of id is dynamic it's keep on changing as of now its delete5 and next time it will be other value.I tried with the same way but could not i even used browser.image(id: '/delete/i').click the regular expression,I am trying to do it on Chrome @Justin Ko

Comment: I even tried with the image button like browser.button(:src,'/abc/zyx/clear.gif').exists? it return true but when I trid to click on it no action but the scroll scroll's down  browser.button(:src,'/abc/zyx/clear.gif').click

Comment: @khan, the comments are very hard to follow as they do not format nicely. You should really create a question that puts all the details together with an example that reproduces the problem.